# Launch a new browser window (small) inside of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, browser, launch

I would like to insert code to launch a default browser in a new SMALL window from within my Excel spreadsheet. Has anyone done this before?

I can already launch my default browser using a SHELL and/or `FollowHyperLink` statement but I need my Excel spreadsheet to remain in focus. If possible I'd like to add it to my existing browser call:

`ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperLink("h.......")`

Comment: Why does yout Workbook need to stay in focus? If you use a selection, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). You also could reactivate your Workbook via `.Activate`-command.

Comment: You could try putting a IE object on a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebBrowser control.  This may need to be added to the ActiveX controls.  Go to Developer Tab > Insert > More Controls > Microsoft Web Browser.

[image: Add more controls to ActiveX]

To control the WebBrowser, use the .Navigate2 (string) command

```
strWebsite = "www.google.com"
Sheet1.WebBrowser1.Navigate2 (strWebsite)
```

Comment: Thanks. I neglected to mention that launching the browser is one of many tasks that designed around the button that launches the browser. Basically its structured as follows:                                                                                                  Private Sub Commandbutton1()                                                                                                do stuff                                                                                                                       ...then launch the website..